# Back to home screen on windows 7 phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, homescreen

My windows phone app checks for network connection when starting and presents the user with a message box if there is no connection. I want the user to go to home screen when the 'OK' button in the message box is clicked - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way your application can do that. You could exit the application by triggering an exception that will be unhandled, but that will count against the app crash index and might cause problems during AppHub Marketplace ingestion.